# Selecting an ID with jQuery to Fade out when you have multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Html:

```
<li class="initial_list initial_first_item click_item" id="reviewsystems A">A</li>
```

When I run this script:

```
$('#reviewsystems').fadeOut(300);
```

It will not work. If I remove the A in the ID it will work. Is there a way to have multiple ID's without converting them to classes?

JsFiddle with Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvf9/

Comment: *"Is there a way to have multiple ID's without converting them to classes?"* No. Why would you want to?

Comment: ID should be unique.  You can use the name attribute if you'd like duplicates and query them using a selector of [name='']

Comment: Classes are the best way to do this. IDs are specifically for _unique_ identifiers :)  You can check if an element has a class with jquery: [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the id has to be unique on the page and it cannot be [a combination of multiple values / contain space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Please, do not refer to w3schools. They have nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I never said they had anything to do with the W3C. I think it's more important that the information is correct, don't you?

Comment: In fact, I haven't said you did. I just said that you could link to proper resource instead of w3schools that has lot of errors: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: *"In HTML, all values are case-insensitive"* Gah! And that's a good reason for not referring to that awful "source" (w3schools). `id` values are **not** case-insensitive. Proof: http://jsbin.com/iyiluv/1

Comment: *"I think it's more important that the information is correct, don't you?"* Yes, that *would* be nice. Which is why you shouldn't refer to w3schools.

Comment: Seth, here's a more up-to-date reference than the 4.01 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute (I've taken the liberty of updating it for you, since you'd already switched to a w3c reference). (+1 restored, btw)

Answer (score 1):

An `id` attribute for an HTML element should be unique for the document:

HTML5 Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

HTML4 Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Further, the id may not contain spaces. It should begin with a letter followed by numerals, hyphens, underscores, colons or period characters:

HTML4 Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

If you want to select multiple HTML elements use the `class` attribute instead.

Comment: The 4.01 spec is hugely out of date. Please refer to [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- HTML5 ref included - thank you. They both seem relevant in illustrating purpose of the 'id' attribute, IMHO.

Comment: @ nathan: No, the 4.01 spec has been superceded. Specifically, it says things about `id` values that are not (and in fact have never been) true in the wild for HTML. The HTML5 spec fixes that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- I was not aware -- what does the 401 spec claim which is incorrect in reference to id values?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have spaces in your id

Refer this http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

You can select using class #id. Here is a working fiddle

```
$(.class#id)...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvf9/1/